# difficulty recalling images from an array in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

This is probably a really simple issue, but I have been staring at it for a while and trying numerous things, and I just can't see the solution, so hoping some kind person can help me out!!

Simply trying to create an array of images or image filenames and then access them later to build a menu. I have everything working except the saving to and recalling of the image names from the array and its getting frustrating!

Here is the cut-down code that I am using to save to and recall from the array:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:30];
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level_%d.png", i]]];
}
```

And then recall:

```
CCMenuItemImage *image = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:imageArray[i] selectedImage:imageArray[i] target:self selector:@selector(levelSelect:)];
```

I think the saving and building of the array is working fine, so I really need to just know how to build the cocos2d menu item using the array pointer.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the UIImage pointer to `itemWithNormalImage`. You need to pass the image name, and then cocos2d will read the image from disk.

So instead of what you have there you need this :

```
CCMenuItemImage *image = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level_%d.png", i] 
                                                selectedImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level_%d.png", i] 
                                                       target:self 
                                                     selector:@selector(levelSelect:)];
```